# PropertyNotFoundException when calling method with commandbutton

Tags: jsf, action, commandbutton, propertynotfoundexception

When I click commandbutton I get this error:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /registracija.xhtml @78,120 action="#{noviKorisnik.kreiraj()}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'noviKorisnik' resolved to null

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Registriraj" action="#{noviKorisnik.kreiraj()}" />
</h:form>
```

Here is my java class

```
@ManagedBean
public class NoviKorisnik {
           ...
   public void kreiraj() { ... }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

> The action attribute accepts a method-binding expression for a backing
>   bean action method to invoke when this component is activated by the
>   user. An action method must be a public method with no parameters that
>   returns a String. The returned string represents the logical outcome
>   of the action (eg. "success", "failure", etc. ) and is used by the
>   JavaServer Faces MVC framework to determine which view to display
>   next.